# getting dropdown selected value using DOJO

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to get a selected value using dojo, from the dropdown without redirecting to another page.

I have tried something like this:

```
dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
     dojo.connect(dojo.byId('#inquiry_type'), "onchange", function(evt) {
         alert("changed!");
         console.log("option Changed to: "+evt.target.value);
         dojo.stopEvent(evt);
     });
});
```

Above code gave me `undefined` in console. Can anyone help me with dojo code?

Comment: Code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the `#` in your call to `dojo.byId`. It just needs the name. Using the `#` syntax is what you would do with `dojo/query`.

Comment: Thanks Kyle Gilbertson!